# How get geolocation info outside of pc "LocalHost"?

Tags: php, ip-geolocation

I want obtain some geolocation informations using a external service (website service), but this works fine only in my pc (localhost using `WampServer` http client); already when my php file is transfered for a remote host (pc), it fails for get these information. Already tried several services of hosts, but still without success.

> PS: My reference of website was [http://ip-api.com/](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:serialized_php).

Here is my code:

```
$ip = $_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));

if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {

  $regiao = $query['regionName'];
  $cidade = $query['city'];
  $isp = $query['isp'];
  $sigla_regiao = $query['region'];
} 
else {
  echo '';
}
```

So, someone have some ideia why this api don't works in a remote host?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your host could be blocking your requests to that API.

Comment: Do you get some kind of error if you don’t suppress the error output in the second line?

Comment: @lxg, putting a `var_dump($query)`, this returns: **bool(false)**

Comment: No, I mean: Please remove the `@` sign in line 2 and tell us if you’re getting an error message.

Comment: @lxg, [this](http://i.imgur.com/k5D2LBN.png) is error that appears.

Comment: That error message is an essential information to your problem. Please add it to your question. Also, you should (almost) *never* suppress PHP errors with `@`. And in the rare cases where you do, you must remove the `@` when you need to investigate problems such as the one you’re having here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you posted, the `file_get_contents` function is not able to create a connection to the remote host. It may be that the access to remote resources is disabled for certain functions.

You can try to access the remote URL with cURL:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ip-api.com/php" . $ipAddr);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec ($curl);
curl_close ($curl); 

if (curl_errno($curl))
    throw new \Exception(sprintf("Connection error %s: %s", curl_errno($curl), curl_error($curl)));

print_r(unserialize($content));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in another provider, you can use the services of https://geoip-db.com

A working JSON example:

```
<?php

    $json = file_get_contents('https://geoip-db.com/json');
    $data = json_decode($json);

    print $data->country_code . '<br>';
    print $data->country_name . '<br>';
    print $data->state . '<br>';
    print $data->city . '<br>';
    print $data->postal . '<br>';
    print $data->latitude . '<br>';
    print $data->longitude . '<br>';
    print $data->IPv4 . '<br>';

?>
```

Or a JSONP callback with php:

```
<?php

    $jsonp = file_get_contents('https://geoip-db.com/jsonp');
    $data = jsonp_decode($jsonp);

    print $data->country_code . '<br>';
    print $data->country_name . '<br>';
    print $data->state . '<br>';
    print $data->city . '<br>';
    print $data->postal . '<br>';
    print $data->latitude . '<br>';
    print $data->longitude . '<br>';
    print $data->IPv4 . '<br>';

    // Strip callback function name and parenthesis
    function jsonp_decode($jsonp) { 
        if($jsonp[0] !== '[' && $jsonp[0] !== '{') { 
           $jsonp = substr($jsonp, strpos($jsonp, '('));
        }
        return json_decode(trim($jsonp,'();'));
    }
?>
```